# How can i make sure an element was appended and exists after ajax request is succesfull?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

If I have use the following, assuming my returned data from the server is an html element like `<span id='hiMark'> text </span>`:

```
...,
success: function(res){
    $(res).appendTo('body');
    $('#hiMark').css({ … }) 
}
```

If I use this, is it safe to use methods on the appended element, I know I can check if an element exists using `.length` and maybe a timer, but, do I have to check in this case ?

If everything goes well server-side, will the `css({})` method execute only after the element was appended ? Or do I need to check first if it exists ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're safe without checking for existence of the element.

Assuming the `res` string contains an element with ID of `hiMark`, it will be appended to the body immediately when `success` runs, and the code will run as expected.

If `res` does *not* contain such an element, any jQuery methods called on that ID will quietly do nothing.

Answer (score -1):

You should check the response with soemthing like this:

```
if(response != null && response!= undefined){
//append my stuff
}
```

or:

```
//if your response is a string  

       if (response != "" ) 

    // if your response is a json object

        if(isEmpty(response)) {
            // response is empty (Would return true in this example)
        } else {
            // response is NOT empty
        }
```